# Java directory polling strategy

Tags: java, polling

There is a directory in which files arrive at unpredictable times, but suppose that probability distribution is normal.

Average intervals for polling must be 1 minute.

Does there exist some strategy - e.g. change near 20% (+ or -) interval for polling or better polling in equal intervals?
If yes - if possible please point to an algorithm in java

Comment: I have some difficulties understanding your question but I'll still give it a try: Since the arrival of files is unpredictable (completely random), the next arrival time doesn't in any way depend on the last arrival time. In addition, since the average polling interval must be 1 minute, the only reasonably strategy is to poll every minute in equal intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of polling yourself you might want to look at [FileAlterationMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/jci/commons-jci-fam/index.html) or [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) or [NIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) (Java 7 only).

Answer (score 2):

It might yet be too early for you, but Java 7 has new class [WatchService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) for monitoring a directory for changes.

Comment: Java 7 was officially released July 28, 2011 :)

Comment: I've been using the new WatchService stuff for a couple months and I really like it. It's pretty much instantaneous notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this using `awaitility`. Please check [here](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage)